# JQuery listen to click and alert with clicked element's href

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title is pretty self explanatory.

```
$(".js").click(function (e) {
        alert('this elements href is: ' + href);
    });
```

How do I replace 'href' with the clicked element's href?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(".js").click(function (e) {
    alert('this elements href is: ' + $(this).attr('href'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
alert('this elements href is: ' + this.href);//best one
```

Or

```
alert('this elements href is: ' + $(this).attr("href"));//but it is unnecessary to wrap an object into another object
```